# A verb for "letting one be in some mental state"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb for "letting one be in (some mental state)" or "letting one to experience ..." in the general sense?

Here is just an example to demonstrate the usage of such word: let's say I want to describe some psychoactive drug letting a person to experience a dreamlike state of mind. (I'm not looking for words with specific meaning like **hallucinate**) What I'm trying to express is the more general idea of "letting one be in some mental state", (without using the word **experience**).

Here is what I mean by that: I want to find a verb to fit in this sentence

> That (verb) me (preposition) [some state of mind].

If such word does not exist, what are some related words to be used?

Comment: Is something like __This *left* me experience ...__ would fit?

Comment: @YohannV. No. Sorry but that is very similar to *let ... experience* which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: A verb saying "be out of the straitjacket of my mind" ?

Comment: It's been years, but I vaguely remember having had the feeling of having been 'taken" or "brought" somewhere: "That 'took/brought (or maybe even 'lifted')' me to a heightened state of awareness."

Comment: You have some very specific conditions. Why must it be a single word? Why must it use a preposition? Isn't your situation more like a person takes a particular medication and what follows is a change in mental... something (reduces anxiety, causes tinnitus, removes pain)? How about this as a generic example: "The drug Amphilaxinib _induces_ euphoria". Does that fit your desired pattern?

Comment: Isn't what you're describing "[getting high](https://www.google.it/search?q=getting+high&oq=getting+high&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)"?

Comment: By "let me" do you mean "made it possible for me"?

Comment: How do you **not** let someone be in a mental state?

Answer (score 2):

The closest verb I can think of is **to hallucinate**,

> to experience a seemingly real perception of something not actually
>   present, typically as a result of a mental disorder or of taking
>   drugs.

Comment: I can't understand why the down vote when the OP didn't _originally_ mention that 'to hallucinate' isn't the word that he is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The altered mental state is usually not a matter of choice with such drugs. It is **induced** rather than facilitated.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that the drug **puts** someone in a certain mental state. For example, "The drug put me in a dreamlike state."

Answer (score 1):

We say:

That  {insert illegal substance of choice} *got me* really high.